# Как исключить предупреждения, связанные со смешением http и https на сайте wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, http, https

Есть сайт на WordPress, на котором имею предупреждения такого плана

> Mixed Content: The page at '[https://сайт/2017/05/02/название-статьи/](https://%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82/2017/05/02/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%B8/)'
>   was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image
>   '[http://сайт/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/logo02.png](http://%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/logo02.png)'. This content
>   should also be served over HTTPS.

Интересно, что показывает на места в хедере и футере, так где адрес задается переменной по такому принципу:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo $cs_theme_option['fav_icon']" ?>" />
```

Как можно от них избавиться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Плагином https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/search-regex/ поменять в контенте протокол ссылок.

Если ссылки в файлах, то и в файлах изменить.

Answer (score 1):

Можно настроить ваш веб сервер так, что бы происходил безусловные редиррект на ssl версию сайта. Тогда такой проблемы не будет. Если вы используете nginx этого можно добиться добавлением подобного примера в конфигурацию сайта:

```
server {
 listen 80;
 server_name example.com;
 if ($scheme = http) {
   return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
 }
}
```

Comment: спасибо, но сертификата на сайте, к сожалению, нет

Comment: @Вася как он по https работает?

Comment: @Alex78191 не очень понял вопрос. я просто в настройках сайта в админке прописал сейчас сайт с https

Comment: @Вася как вы можете использовать HTTPS без сертификата?

Comment: @Alex78191 не знаю. прописал в настройках - сайт открывается и работает, причем с разных мест

Comment: @Вася почему nginx настроить не можете?

Comment: @Alex78191 а подскажите как или ссылку на статью

Comment: @Вася Про что статью?

Comment: @Alex78191 про настройку nginx для подобного случая

Comment: @Вася вам в ответе написали что сделать

Comment: @Alex78191 это не дало окончательный результат - не все ссылки заменились. вы упомянули про nginx - вот я и решил поинтересоваться